# Make a number clickable using Jquery

Tags: jquery, mura

I was able to obtain the following way to make phone number clickable:

```
<a href={{'tel:'+e.Phone}}>{{e.Phone | PhoneNumber}}</a>
```

However, it conflicts with MURA CMS.

My question is their an alternative to the following code so Mura can render it correctly?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I don't know MURA, but I see 2 things worth to mention:
1: the href attr.'s value supposed to be between quotation marks 
2: Some templeting system don't like string concatenations between their output tag. Try the following instead: <a href="tel:{{e.Phone}}">

Comment: Why are you using the `{{ }}`? I have never seen that before. As Burnee said, you should be able to just wrap the attributes in quotes; either double `"` or single `'`. If the variables are ColdFusion variables then they should be between hashtags `#`. If the issue is you trying to add this content within the Mura text editor, then try using the Mura tags `[mura]` or `[m]` instead of the hashtags.

Comment: @Burnee I saw an example online where you do that and it didnt work on my end. That being said, I am grabbing the phone numbers in a database. Yes Ihave tried <a href="tel:{{e.Phone}}"> and it didnt work properly. Instead, it leave it blank where the phone number should be

Comment: @Miguel-F If I do use the Mura tags, what would I be replacing?

Comment: You would only use the Mura tags if you are trying to embed this code within the CMS text editor. In that case the Mura tags replace the normal ColdFusion hashtags `#` that surround variables. So instead of `#e.Phone#` it would be `[mura]e.Phone[/mura]`.

Comment: The complete solution of my previous answer should look like this:
<a href="'tel:{{e.Phone}}">{{e.Phone | PhoneNumber}}</a>

Comment: @Miguel-F e.Phone is not in coldfusion but in Mura editor

Comment: Where is `e.Phone` being defined? Is it from a query, an extended attribute, ???